# separability of a certain space of continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $O$ be an open subset of the separable Hilbert space $H.$ Let $E$ be a separable Banach space. Is it true that $C^0_b(O;E),$ the space of bounded continuous maps $O\rightarrow E$,  endowed with the $C^0$-norm, is separable? If YES, where can I find I proof of this fact?

Comment: Is $C^0$ the uniform norm?  If so, the answer is clearly no.  You can find an uncountable set such that the distance between any two is 1; for each set of integers pick a continuous function which is 1 on those integers and 0 on the rest.

Comment: Er, here I am thinking of taking $O = H = \mathbb{R}$ and $E = \mathbb{R}$ as well.

Comment: @Nate: I am confused. The space $C^0_b(\mathbb{R})$ is separable! The proof is simple - it follows from the separability of $C^0([0,1]).$ Fix a $\delta>0$ sufficiently small and cover $\mathbb{R}$ by intervals of the form $[n-\delta,n+1+\delta].$ On each of these there is a countable dense set. Now glue all these together on the overlapping parts to make the resulting function continuous. This is how you arrive at your countable dense set!

Comment: @Orbicular: With countably many choices on each of countably many intervals, there seem to be continuum many things you can get by gluing.

Comment: @Orbicular: But don't you end up "gluing a countable set to itself countably many times"?? That doesn't give a countable set: think about the cardinality of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: Well, one uses a fixed way of interpolation. Let $\phi:[-\delta,\delta]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a smooth function with $\phi(t)=1$ for $t<-\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $\phi(t)=0$ for $t>\frac{\delta}{2}.$ Then you interpolate beween a and b by $\phi(t)a(t)+(1-\phi(t))b(t).$ You can do this for every overlapping of the intervals mentioned above. Thus everything is parametrized by $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @Orbicular: No-- just consider Ady's counter-example.  Or more concretely, in $C_b^0(\mathbb R)$, for each $A\subseteq\mathbb Z$, we can find a continuous function $f_A:\mathbb R\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f_A(n+1/2)=0$ if $n\not\in A$ and $f_A(n+1/2)=1$ if $n\in A$ (think: glue together little triangles, or a bump function if you wish).  Then $\|f_A - f_B\|=1$ if $A\not=B$, so certainly $C^0_b(\mathbb R)$ is not separable.

Comment: @Orbicular: See also http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst;task=show_msg;msg=1842.0001

Comment: @all the guys: You are absolutely right, sorry! I was just not seeing things clearly... Thanks!

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  This is a good question, with a nice, simple answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative. For, pick some non-zero $e$ in $E$, and
choose a surjection $\rho\in C\left(O,\mathbb{R}\right)$  (there exists
!).

Next, consider the (uncountable, uniformly discrete) family of functions {
$f_{A}$; $A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ nonempty } $\subset C_{b}^{0}\left(O,E\right)$, expressed by $$f_{A}\left(x\right):=\arctan\left(dist\left(\rho\left(x\right),A\right)\right)\cdot e$$
    $\left(x\in O\right).$

Comment: @all the guys: You are absolutely right, sorry! I was just not seeing things clearly... Thanks! Now at least I understand those things...